# Connect EASession after entering ibeacon

Tags: ibeacon, eaaccessory

I wonder if the background time that an app receives when entering an ibeacon region can be used for opening a session with an external accessory object. Can the app then also keep on running in the background while the session remains open?
This of course assuming that the external-accessory background mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not tried this myself, I do not see any reason why it wouldn't work.  You would need to have a legitimate reason in Apple's eyes to use the external-accessory background mode in order to get your app approved.

Assuming you have this, as soon as the app sees an iBeacon in the background, the app gets about 5 seconds of run time, which should generally be sufficient to establish a connection to an external accessory.  If the connection is made, and the app is exchanging data with it regularly, the external-accessory background mode should keep it going in the background indefinitely, so long as the connection to the external accessory stays open.  So long as this is true, the app will probably be able to get ranging updates in the background indefinitely, too.

It doesn't take a huge leap of logic to see that you could build a device that behaves as an external accessory and an iBeacon simultaneously, and use this to get around the usual iBeacon background rules.  That said, you'd need to be careful that Apple doesn't think this is illegitimate, or the app could get rejected quickly.  To avoid this rejection, you probably would need to be providing some benefit to the end-user via that external accessory channel.